# Socket.io connects more than once

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to display my connection to a page with socket, but when I reload my page, the message is displayed 2 times, when i reload again, 3 times etc ...

Here is the code node js.

```
.get('/compte/', function(req, res) {
res.render('compte.ejs');
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on("new_client", function(message){
       console.log(message);
    });
});
```

});

Here is the code html / script.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

        socket.emit('new_client', "hello");
    </script>
```

and here is the displaying after 2 reload.

```
hello

hello
hello

hello
hello
hello
```

I hope to have been clear about my problem.
Thank you.

Comment: That's because you're creating a new listener everytime you visit the page. Move it outside of the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your client does not connect more than once, but you add an event listener for SocketIO connections on each get request of `/compte/`. They are accumulated in `io.sockets`.

Try moving the SocketIO event handler out of the request handler:

```
.get('/compte/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('compte.ejs');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on("new_client", function(message){
       console.log(message);
    });
});
```